# Wordpress on iis error 500 for uploaded files

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, hosting, file-permissions

I am using iis to host a WordPress website. Whenever i upload an image, i have to go to the uploaded image path and give "IIS_IUSRS" permission to that pic file for it to be able to be displayed in an image tag. If i do not do this i get 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there a way that "IIS_IUSRS" get permissions on every future files in the folder.

> I already have tried to give everyone permission on uploads folder,
>   but still does not works

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing child object permissions entries from IIS.

1. Connect to IIS manager.
2. Select the website and navigate to folder Uploads.
3. Right Click on the Uploads folder and Click Edit Permissions.
4. Click on Security Tab.
5. Select the IIS_IUSRS username and click on Advanced button.
   [image]
6. Check the checkbox "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object".
   [image]
7. Click on Apply and OK.

Comment: I have done this earlier, it works for current files, but now say i upload a new file it does not apply to this file

Comment: Make sure that your website's web user has modify permissions on upload folder. Also, this should help you.
http://www.mbrauchler.com/wordpress-image-upload-problem-using-iis-on-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This issue was bugging my head for 2 or more hours. Although all the permissions were there, The last check box did the trick.